# How to slow down the last few frames in a CSS sprite animation?

Tags: css, css-animations, css-sprites

I have a CSS sprite animation.

I would like the animation to slow down, before it stops. 
[image]

I have a total of 10 Frames. 
Frame 1-5 should be 0.8s, Frame 6-7 should be 2s and Frame 8-10 should be 3s.

```
.hi3 {
  width: 73px;
  height: 75px;
  background-image: url("../img/dice3.fw.png");

  -webkit-animation: play .8s steps(10) forwards;
     -moz-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
      -ms-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
       -o-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
          animation: play .8s steps(10) forwards;   
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
   to { background-position: -722px; }
}

@keyframes play {
  from { background-position:    0px; }
  to { background-position: -722px; }
}
```

Is it possible to do this all in CSS? This animation is being used in a hybrid IONIC app.

Comment: Was that what you needed (or) is your question different?

Comment: Thanks Harry, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a total of 10 Frames. Frame 1-5 should be 0.8s, Frame 6-7 should be 2s and Frame 8-10 should be 3s. Is it possible to do this all in CSS?

**Yes**, it is possible but for that the [`animation-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) needs to be modified and `@keyframes` should be coded accordingly. The ***`steps` function divides frames into equidistant steps*** based on the no. of steps that is provided as parameter and jumps from one step to another.

The below is what MDN has to say about this [timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/timing-function):

> The steps() functional notation defines a step function dividing the domain of output values in equidistant steps.

Because of the above, the `steps()` function cannot be used to create the effect that you are looking for (as each step is equidistant and so has equal timing).

---

**Solution:**

The following are the things that need to be done in-order to get the output that you're looking for:

- Calculate the total `animation-duration` based on your expectation. My interpretation is that you need .8s for each of the first 5 frames (4s), 2s for the next two (4s) and 3s for the next three (9s) and so the total `animation-duration` should be set as 17s. (**Note:** Alternately, if you mean that all the first 5 frames should be completed within 0.8s and so on, then duration will be 5.8s).
- Change the `animation-timing-function` to `linear` because the `steps()` function will not work as mentioned above.
- Calculate the splits for `@keyframes` based on the no. of seconds for each frame and animation's total duration. Formula would be (No. of seconds for the frame / Total Duration * 100) and so the first 5 frames would roughly need to be present for 4.70% of the animation, the next 2 for 11.76% and the last 3 for 17.64%. (**Note:** Splits would change if you were looking for 5.8s duration).
- Now based on the splits, write the `@keyframes` selectors (the percentage values). The key thing to note while writing the keyframe selectors is that a sprite animation should typically jump from one frame to another (not a linear slide movement) and so, each frame should be shown until the time when the next frame has to be shown. For example, frame 2 has to be shown at `4.70%` and so the frame 1's `background-position` should be maintained from `0%` to `4.69%`.

---

**Demo with 17s duration:** <sup>(each of the first 5 frames get 0.8s, each of the next 2 get 2s and each of the last 3 get 3s)</sup>

```css
.hi {
  width: 50px;
  height: 72px;
  background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");
  animation: play 17s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes play {
  0%, 4.69% {     /* 0.8s */
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  4.70%, 9.39% {  /* 0.8s */
    background-position: -50px;
  }
  9.40%, 14.09% { /* 0.8s */
    background-position: -100px;
  }
  14.10%, 18.79% { /* 0.8s */
    background-position: -150px;
  }
  18.80%, 23.49% { /* 0.8s */
    background-position: -200px;
  }
  23.5%, 35.25% {  /* 2s */
    background-position: -250px;
  }
  35.26%, 47.01% { /* 2s */
    background-position: -300px;
  }
  47.02%, 64.65% { /* 3s */
    background-position: -350px;
  }
  64.66%, 82.29% { /* 3s */
    background-position: -400px;
  }
  82.3%, 100% { /* 3s */
    background-position: -450px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png" />
<div class="hi"></div>
```

**Demo with 5.8s duration:** <sup>(the first 5 frames get 0.8s in total, the next 2 get 2s in total and final 3 get 3s in total)</sup>

```css
.hi {
  width: 50px;
  height: 72px;
  background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");
  animation: play 5.8s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes play {
  0%, 2.74% {     /* 0.16s */
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  2.75%, 5.49% {  /* 0.16s */
    background-position: -50px;
  }
  5.50%, 8.24% { /* 0.16s */
    background-position: -100px;
  }
  8.25%, 10.99% { /* 0.16s */
    background-position: -150px;
  }
  11.00%, 13.74% { /* 0.16s */
    background-position: -200px;
  }
  13.75%, 30.99% {  /* 1s */
    background-position: -250px;
  }
  31.00%, 48.24% { /* 1s */
    background-position: -300px;
  }
  48.25%, 65.49% { /* 1s */
    background-position: -350px;
  }
  65.50%, 82.74% { /* 1s */
    background-position: -400px;
  }
  82.75%, 100% { /* 3s */
    background-position: -450px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png" />
<div class="hi"></div>
```

> **Disclaimer:** The sprite image is not my own and it was adapted from [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/) found through Google search.